# PHP - I cannot update my database

Tags: php

Can anyone help me?

It seems I cannot update my database using this code I made.

I dont know wats wrong.

I want to update the entire row of a specified ID while displaying the old data in a form.

How do I correct this?

```
<?php //upd_emp.php

  mysql_connect ("localhost", "root","")  or die (mysql_error());
  mysql_select_db ("emp_db0");
  $id =$_POST['emp_idn'];

  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM emp_tbl WHERE emp_id  = '$id'");
  $test = mysql_fetch_array($result);
  if (!$result) 
    {
    die("Error: Data not found..");
    }
            $fname=$test['fname'] ;
            $mname= $test['mname'] ;                    
            $lname=$test['lname'] ;
            $email=$test['email'] ;

     if(isset($_POST['SAVE']))
     {  
 $f_save = $_POST['f_name'];
 $m_save = $_POST['m_name'];
 $l_save = $_POST['l_name'];
 $e_save = $_POST['e_mail'];

mysql_query("UPDATE emp_tbl SET fname ='$f_save', mname ='$m_save',
     lname ='$l_save',email ='$e_save' WHERE emp_id = '$id'")
            or die(mysql_error()); 
echo "Saved!";


     }

    ?>

    <form action = "upd_emp.php" method="post">

            First Name:<input type="text" name="f_name" value="<?php echo $fname ?>"/>
            Middle Initial:<input type="text" name="m_name" value="<?php echo $mname ?>"/>
            Last Name:<td><input type="text" name="l_name" value="<?php echo $lname ?>"/>
            Email Add:<input type="text" name="e_mail" value="<?php echo $email ?>"/>
            <input type="submit" name="save" value="SAVE" />

     </form>



This code here at top came from a form page after clicking the submit button "view.php"
   <?php $id =$_POST['emp_idn']; ?>
```

Comment: change `name="save"` to `name="SAVE"` - if(isset($_POST['SAVE']))

Comment: Hi, this need basic debugging first. What goes wrong where exactly? Use test outputs to find out. Also, you are not doing proper error checking - which you need for useful information on what goes wrong. http://php.net/mysql_error

Comment: By the way, your inputs are NOT safe. You need to protect your variables with a function like `mysql_real_escape_string` to prevent SQL injections.

Comment: where do you send emp_idn (id) ?

Comment: im still doing basic stuff from the time being. As for the SQL injection, this is a draft in order for me to understand updating the database. I will remove the problem in the final phase. the emp_idn(id) came from a previous page. I sent the variable here in this page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  are using

```
$_POST['SAVE']
```

where as in form it is "save"

change your $_POST

to

```
$_POST['save'];
```

Comment: Correct, but wouldn't it be infinitely more useful to teach the OP how to debug stuff like this by themselves?

Comment: True but sometimes there are new bees who are very new to PHP/Coding for them this kind of detailed description will be helpful so that they can keep in mind while they implement it

Comment: Well, they still don't learn anything useful. They'll just come back to Stack Overflow next time they have the problem. Not saying this is a bad answer - I've given answers like this myself. They just don't really help the OP develop as a programmer

Comment: Do u suggest any other alternative. You seems to be experienced :) Well nice talking to u :)

Comment: I already tried fixing the $_POST['save']; but didnt fix the error. hehehe. Im still a noob trying to understand all the stuff im doing as for the moment

Answer (score 0):

Change this below condition

```
 if(isset($_POST['SAVE']))
```

By this

```
 if(isset($_POST['save']))
```

You made mistake to take name of submit button.